# How do I sync playlists to a Windows Phone?

Tags: zune, music, xbox-music

I've had my Lumia 820 for 2 weeks and I'm struggling with getting playlists (from my exisitng MP3 library) onto the phone.

- m3u files arent recognised
- Zune music manager doesn't recognise the phone
- Windows Phone App (Desktop Version) can't create or copy playlists (fails with error 83000000)
- Windows Phone App (Metro Version) can't create or copy playlists (fails with error 83000000)
- Windows Music App / Xbox Music playlists are always empty
- Windows Media Player syncs playlists but it copies all the files over again each time

So far, out of all the apps, Windows Media Player is the only way that works, and it's far from perfect. Are there other ways to sync playlists? Is there any way to get the phone to just recognise m3u playlists?

**UPDATE: Thursday, May 30, 2013** Windows Phone app for Metro worked for a while, but has now stopped working with error code 83000000. It appears to copy the music, create multiple entries in the Media Library and create an empty playlist. This results in an album with multiple copies of the same track. However, if you delete any of these entries from the album, (via long press, delete) the file is deleted, leaving you with an album with non working tracks.

The new version of the Windows Phone app for Desktop has the same issue.

Comment: Windows Media Player is the best I have found so far, not as nice as Zune was for doing this

Comment: Here's an article with a conversion tool.  Haven't tried it myself - http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-convert-zune-playlistzpl-to-windows-media-player-playlistwpl/ ....

Comment: @JoeHealy that tool converts zune playlists (ZPL) to windows playlists (WPL). There are tools out there which convert M3U directly to WPL, but then I'm left using WMP to sync again, which means it copies all the files over again. I want something else that can sync, or an app on the phone that will recognise m3u files

Comment: You might want to retry the desktop sync apps. They were just updated today. http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/get-the-sync-apps

Comment: The newly released desktop version fails to copy playlists. It throws an error (error 83000000) for each track and creates an empty playlist on the phone. The Metro version is still the only version that works, and even then it doesn't always

Comment: UPDATE: Metro version no longer works for me. I have to unaccept this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the windows phone 8 [sync tool](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/get-the-sync-apps)?  This can sync music playlists, video, ringtones and other files to and from you Windows 8 phone. There is a wizard on that site if you do not know which version  to install.

Comment: Desktop version doesn't allow me to sync, but the metro version does. However, it can hang in the middle of a sync if I minimize the app. You have to keep checking back to make sure it's still going.

Comment: Metro apps are generally only allowed minimal running time when they are not "active." One thing you might want to try, if it works for you, is to try snapping the metro app to the side. This way it is still active and will not be cleaned up or suspended by Windows 8.